# Building thrift application on Windows 7

Tags: c++, thrift, wdk

Is there any way to build thrift 0.8 on Windows?

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 ( v9 ), boost 1.48 and WDK 7

I found several errors in my test...
for example, I had to change:

in concurrency/threadmanager.h

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp> to
#include <shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <tr1/functional> to
#include <tr1/functional.hpp>
```

then I found /windows/tagertversion.h that try to include winsdkver.h, but I can't find it, also if it should be included into WDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those changes suggest that you're including completely different files. `boost::shared_ptr` is still in the `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` file. If you couldn't include it, then you didn't have your include paths set up correctly.

Comment: files are:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/lib/cpp/src/concurrency/ThreadManager.h
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/lib/cpp/src/windows/TargetVersion.h

I'm sure I have included well boost and wdk, becouse in other projects they work, instead in thrift I have included this: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/thrift/trunk/lib/cpp/src/